# Verifying DFS complexity for directed and un-directed graph

Tags: java, time-complexity

Question:

1. Is DFS complexity different for a directed and undirected graph ?
2. If yes, then directed graph complexity is O(V + E), and undirected graph complexity is O(E) ?, where E is edges and V is the vertices ?
3. If yes then is the following commented - explanation for O(V+E) complexity for directed graph correct ?

```
          /*
         * Although this piece looks like it is O(V * E), it is actually O(V + E)

         * This is because, for each node, we dont do dfs across the full tree.
         * ie 
         *    A -> C
         *    |
         *    V
         *    B
         * Here A has a directed edge to B and C.
         * This means that when 'Node' == A then 'dfs' code would cost O(E)
         * But when the 'node' == B then 'dfs' would cost O(1), since B does not have any outgoing edge
         * and when the 'node' == C then 'dfs' would cost O(1), since C does not have any outgoing edge   
         * This O(E + 1 + 1) = O(E)
         * And O(A + B + C) = O(V)
         * 
         */
         for (T node : graph) {
            if (dfs(graph, node, visitedNodes, completedNodes)) return true;
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, the complexity of DFS for both directed graph and undirected graph should be the same. And it appears your argument for the complexity only works for a particular graph, I have provided a more general argument below for your reference.

#### Notation

Given a graph *G = (V, E)*, we denote by *n = |V|* the number of vertices of the graph, and *m = |E|* the number of edges of the graph. The DFS algorithm is given recursively as below:

```
Mark all vertices as unexplored

DFS(graph G, start vertex s)
- Mark s as explored
- For every edge (s, v):
    - If v is unexplored
        - DFS(G, v)
```

#### What is the complexity of DFS on a graph?

It actually depends on the underlying data structure you are using to implement the graph.

- *Adjacency matrix* is an *n* by *n* matrix, where the *a<sub>ij</sub>* (i.e. the entry at the *i*-th row and the *j*-th) denotes the *number* of edges from vertex *i* to vertex *j*. The complexity of DFS is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* in this case.
- *Adjacency list* is a collection of *n* unordered lists for each vertex, each list represents the set of neighbors of its vertex. The complexity of DFS is *O(n + m)* **(for both directed and undirected graph)** in this case.

#### Proof

First consider using **adjacency list** to represent the graph, where the list for vertex *v* consists of pointers to the *adjacent vertices*. Let *m<sub>v</sub>* denotes the number of edges adjacent to the vertex *v*. It follows that the number of work required for invoking `DFS(G, v)` is 1 + *m<sub>v</sub>* (marking *v* as explored, and then looping over *m<sub>v</sub>* edges). Observe that starting from an arbitrary vertex *s*, the DFS algorithm is invoked recursively on each vertex *at most* once (when the vertex is unexplored), hence the total work required is *at most*:

*∑<sub>v ∈ V</sub> (1 + m<sub>v</sub>) = |V| + ∑<sub>v ∈ V</sub> m<sub>v</sub>*

In a *directed* graph, we have *∑<sub>v ∈ V</sub> m<sub>v</sub> = |E|*, whereas in an *undirected* graph, we have *∑<sub>v ∈ V</sub> m<sub>v</sub> = 2 |E|* (this is because *(u, v) and (v, u) are regarded as the same edge in an undirected graph*). In both cases, the total work required is *O(|V| + |E|) = O(n + m)*.

If we are using **adjacency matrix** to represent the graph, the DFS algorithm will also be recursively invoked *at most* once for each vertex. However, if we want to loop over all the outgoing edges of a vertex *v* in this case, we **have to** loop over all the entries on the row corresponding to *v* in the adjacency matrix to find all non-zero entries, which requires *n = |V|* scans in total. Therefore the total work required for DFS is *O(|V|<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)* in this case.